# Python script doesn't work when executed from NRPE

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I have developed a Nagios plugin using Python3 for checking some backups. If I run the script from the client, everything works fine, but when I run it from the Nagios server using NRPE, it doesn't recognize certain regexes. I have tried these regexes and they are fine, so I assume this is a problem between NRPE and Python.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably something to do with the account NRPE is running under, specifically environment variables or permissions.

(It's hard to say more with the information you've provided.)

Try running the script as the NRPE account and see if that gives you any insight.